# How can I prompt for input using Selenium/Webdriver and use the result?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I would like to allow for user input and make some decisions based on it. If I do this:

```
driver.execute_script("prompt('Enter smth','smth')")
```

I get a nice prompt, but I cannot use it's value. Is there any way of showing an input box to the user, and use the value typed there?

EDIT: This is my script:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = Firefox()
    driver.execute_script("window.promptResponse=prompt('Enter smth','smth')")
    a = driver.execute_script("var win = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); return win.promptResponse")
    print "got back %s" % a
```

And this exits with the following exception:

```
    a = driver.execute_script("var win = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); return win.promptResponse")
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.12.1-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 385, in ex
ecute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.12.1-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 153, in ex
ecute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.12.1-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 110, in
 check_response
    if 'message' in value:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

What am I not doing right?

EDIT: I tried to do like prestomanifesto suggested, here's the output:

```
In [1]: from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

In [2]: f = Firefox()

In [3]: a = f.ex
f.execute              f.execute_async_script f.execute_script

In [3]: a = f.execute_script("return prompt('Enter smth','smth')")

In [4]: a
Out[4]: {u'text': u'Enter smth'}

In [5]: a
Out[5]: {u'text': u'Enter smth'}

In [6]: class(a)
  File "<ipython-input-6-2d2ff4f61612>", line 1
    class(a)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [7]: type(a)
Out[7]: dict
```

Answer (score 7):

Hope this helps others:

```
# selenium (3.4.1)  python (3.5.1)
driver.execute_script("var a = prompt('Enter Luffy', 'Luffy');document.body.setAttribute('data-id', a)")
time.sleep(3)  # must 
print(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('data-id'))   # get the text
```

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in using the prompt box in javascript. But the prompt box value should be assigned to a global variable and then you could use this variable later.
something like this:

`driver.execute_script("window.promptResponse=prompt('Enter smth','smth')")`

and then retrieve the value from the same global variable.

```
a = driver.execute_script("var win = this.browserbot.getUserWindow(); return win.promptResponse")
```

you probably need to cast the return.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my question with the result of running your code. Can you spot what I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I had the same question too and this is what works for me: Some credit to @Devin

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException

while True:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("var a = prompt('Enter Luffy', 'Luffy');document.body.setAttribute('user-manual-input', a)")
        sleep(5)  # must 
        print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('user-manual-input')) # get the text
        break

     except (UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
        pass
```

The prompt will wait 5 seconds for input. If no input is provided, it will prompt the user for input again.

Answer (score 1):

[Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is a GUI based library you can use to take input from the user at runtime. This will keep the program on wait unless the user enters the information. For pre-designed dialogue box you can refer to this [link](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_dialogs.php). Although its late but may be it might help somebody else.

Comment: How does Tkinter work in Production Server as that does not have a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Based on other answers, I built the following code that works for me:

```
def is_alert_present(driver):
    try:
        driver.switch_to.alert
        return True
    except exceptions.NoAlertPresentException:
        return False


def prompt_user(driver, text):

    driver.execute_script('var a = prompt ("{}");document.body.setAttribute("data-id", a)'.format(text))
    while is_alert_present(driver):
        sleep(4)
    v = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('data-id')

    return v if v != 'null' else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not return the value directly?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = Firefox()
    a = driver.execute_script("return prompt('Enter smth','smth')")
    print "got back %s" % a
```

Works for me in C#. Admittedly it's a slightly older Selenium version but I wouldn't expect the `execute_script` function to change much.

Comment: The thing is, `execute_script` returns immediately. It doesn't block until I enter input. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the technique suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8532999/1077279)

The basic idea is:

- Issue Selenium commands up to the point where you want to capture user input.
- Get the user input in the console window with `raw_input()`
- Continue your Selenium commands

In Python for instance:

```
#Navigate to the site
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/")
#Find the search box on the page
queryBox = self.driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"))
#Wait for user text input in the console window
text = raw_input("Enter something")
#Send the retrieved input to the search box
queryBox.SendKeys(text)
#Submit the form
queryBox.Submit()
```

Comment: I would like to keep it GUI based.

Answer (score -1):

If you guys using selenium 2.28 like me this will do the trick just like @Baz1nga say

```
//Open the prompt inbox and setup global variable to contain the result
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.promptResponse = prompt(\"Please enter captcha\");");

//Handle javascript prompt box and get value. 
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
try {
  Thread.sleep(6000);
} catch (Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Cannot sleep because of headache");
}
alert.accept();
String ret = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse;");
```

Comment: You shouldn't just take the previous answer and port it to Javascript for a question about Python..