# get around capcha in selenium

Tags: java, unit-testing, firefox, selenium

I have a lot of automated tests to run once I've logged into the site I'm unit testing, but I can't (don't have permissions) remove the capcha from the login page.

is there any way to use selenium 2.0 such that I could start the WebDriver instance of, say, firefox, then do the capcha by hand and then have the WebDriver (I use the java jar of the server) "take over" from there?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following snippet:

1. loads BING homepage
2. prompts the user to perform a search
3. once the search results are loaded in the test browser, the user is prompted to press the ENTER key
4. the first result link from the user's search is clicked

   ```
   driver.get("http://www.bing.com");

   System.out.println("Loaded BING homepage");
   System.out.println("Search for some term and then press ENTER");

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   reader.readLine();

   System.out.println("Clicking on the first link ...");

   driver.findElements(By.className("sa_wr")).get(0)
         .findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();

   Thread.sleep(3000);

   driver.quit();
   ```

You can use similar code to load the login page, prompt the tester to enter CAPTCHA, and then proceed with the test.

Comment: really simple, should have thought of that myself. good answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInputExample(){
    Scanner inputText = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args ){
        String search= inputText.next();
    }
}
```