# Ruby/Selenium WebDriver - Pausing test and waiting for user input, i.e. user inputs captcha

Tags: ruby, selenium, captcha, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the Selenium WebDriver and Ruby to perform some automation and I ran into a problem of a captcha around step 3 of a 5 step process.

I'm throwing all the automation in a rake script so I'm wondering is there a command to pause or break the script running temporarily until I enter data into the captcha and then continue running on the next page.

Answer (score 1):

To build on seleniumnewbie's answer and assuming that you have access to the console the script is running on:

```
print "Enter Captcha"
captchaTxt = gets.chomp
yourCaptchaInputWebdriverElement.send_keys captchaTxt
```

If you just want to pause and enter the captcha in your browser, you can just have it prompt at the console to do that very thing and it'll just sit there.

```
print "Enter the captcha in your browser"
gets
```

You could also set the implicit wait to decently long period of time so that Selenium would automatically see the next page and move out.  However, this would leave the important Captcha step (for documenting / processes sake) out of your test unless you're pretty anal with your commenting.

Since this is an actively participating test requiring user input I would say that making the tester press "enter" on the console is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing the test in a script, all you need to do is add a sleep in your test i.e. 'sleep 100' for example.

However, it is bad to add arbitrary sleeps in tests. You can also do something like "Wait for title 'foo'" where 'foo' is the title of the page in Step 4. It need not be title, it can be anything, but you get the idea. Wait for something semantic which indicates that step 3 is done and step 4 is ready to start.

This way, its more targeted wait.

Answer (score 0):

This has been implemented in JAVA, but similar technique.Your solution could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530875/get-around-capcha-in-selenium)