# Selenium IDE: Show prompt and return user input to field

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I created a prompt in selenium IDE by using:

```
Command  :   storeEval
Target   :   prompt("please enter code");
Value    :   test
```

How can I return this code and use it further in the IDE? e.g. writing it to a specific input field.

I just want the code to wait until it receives the return value from the prompt and then use that value to insert it to a specific field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give the runtime input in selenium IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464452/how-to-give-the-runtime-input-in-selenium-ide)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use the rollup feature in order to repeat this step. Have a look at [this source](https://sanjitmohanty.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/using-the-rollup-feature-of-selenium/). It will give you an overview of the rollup feature.

I don't believe there is any other way to repeat the function.

Comment: Why should I need to repeat this step?

Comment: My understanding of your post is that you want to reuse the above code but don't want to have to repeat it? Is that correct?

Comment: No, I just want the code to wait until it receives the return value from the prompt and then use that value to insert it to a specific field.