# Call prompt inside a Selenium Test

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to ask for user input with `prompt` inside of a Selenium test.
I tried the following:

```
driver.prompt("user input");
```

But I get the error `TypeError: prompt is not a function`. Is there any possibility to call `prompt()` inside a Selenium test?
It seems to be possible in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8175328).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is telling you the reason - the "driver" object doesn't have the `prompt()` function. Generating prompts is done by the browser and webdriver - its "driver" instance in your case - is just an interface to interact with it.
So to achieve what you wabt, you need to instruct *the browser* to run a js code. And that's done through the `executeScript()` function:

```
driver.executeScript('prompt("user input");')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This opens up a prompt for less than a second and gives me the error `UnexpectedAlertOpenError: Dismissed user prompt dialog: user input`. Adding the line `driver.switchTo().alert()` keeps the prompt opened. How do I get the value the user has entered to check it in an assertion?

Comment: It's a little different question than the one you've originally posted - thus, please look here, that's what you're looking for now, how to get there prompt value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8178126/3446126