# Python - How to use user input for login information prompt

Tags: python, authentication, instagram

I am kinda new to Python and tried to make a script that automatically logs you in on Instagram. However I was not happy with the solution to only put it in your code, I want to ask for the credentials when running the script, then use it on the Instagram login page. This is the code I got so far:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from  random import randint


username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep (2)
driver.execute_script("""
   var l = document.getElementsByClassName("pbNvD    FrS-d sjcY5    gD9tr")[0];
   l.parentNode.removeChild(l);
""")

driver.execute_script("""
   var l = document.getElementsByClassName("RnEpo  Yx5HN      _4Yzd2")[0];
   l.parentNode.removeChild(l);
""")


sleep (1)
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('password')


button_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')
button_login.click()
sleep(randint(3,5))

notnow = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > div > div > div > div > button')
notnow.click()
sleep(randint(3,5))
notificationnotnow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
notificationnotnow.click()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: refer this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175328/how-can-i-prompt-for-input-using-selenium-webdriver-and-use-the-result/8178126

Comment: Why use the driver.execute. There is no need to do that.

Comment: Because when I open the browser, there is always a cookie popup, which prevents the code from working properly, and I don't want to change my cookie settings for this. So instead I told the script to delete the 2 classes that form the cookie popup,  so that it just disappears and doesn't stand in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why do you pass a string ("username" and "password") name instead of (username and password)**

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from  random import randint


username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')


sleep (5)
username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_input.send_keys(password)


button_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(3) > button')
button_login.click()
sleep(randint(3,5))

notnow = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > div > div > div > div > button')
notnow.click()
sleep(randint(3,5))
notificationnotnow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]')
notificationnotnow.click()
```

Comment: While this code might be correct, to be a good answer and helpful to OP, it might be nice to add some explanation what OP did wrong, why it is wrong and how your code solves these issues

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here

```
sleep (1)
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('password')
```

You are passing the words 'username' and 'password' instead of passing the variables `username`, `password`. When you put them inside quotes they become string.

You should try the following:

```
sleep (1)
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys(username)
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(password)
```

Comment: You also pass a string instead of the variable name.

Comment: @SharimIqbal that was a mistake, I have corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: Why does he use the driver.execute there is no need.

Comment: @SharimIqbal Because when I open the browser, there is always a cookie popup, which prevents the code from working properly, and I don't want to change my cookie settings for this. So instead I told the script to delete the 2 classes that form the cookie popup, so that it just disappears and doesn't stand in the way.